# Storing each column in a separate dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there an efficient way to store each column of a tab-delimited file in a separate dictionary using python?

A sample input file: (Real input file contains thousands of lines and hundreds of columns. Number of columns is not fixed, it changes frequently.)

```
A B C
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

I need to print values in column `A`:

```
for cell in mydict["A"]:
    print cell
```

and to print values in the same row:

```
for i in range(1, numrows):
    for key in keysOfMydict:
        print mydict[key][i]
```

Comment: Why don't you just store the rows and use a dictionary to map column names to their index?

Comment: If the number of columns is not fixed, what would you expect to print in a row where the column is missing ?

Comment: Depending on what else you're doing with your data you might find interesting the pandas library: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#getting

Comment: @GWW, the main computation is on columns. It may be inefficient to retrieve a row, since one cell within this row will be used, other cells will not be used.

Comment: @alfasin, the number of cells in each row is same. I meant that I do not want solutions which contain hard-coded column count and column names, because these codes are not manageable when the number of columns frequently changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `DictReader` from the `csv` module:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
   rows = list(reader) # If your file is not large, you can
                       # consume it entirely

   # If your file is large, you might want to 
   # step over each row:
   #for row in reader:
   #    print(row['A'])

for row in rows:
   print(row['A'])
```

@Marius made a good point - that you might be looking to collect all columns separately by their header.

If that's the case, you'll have to adjust your reading logic a bit:

```
from collections import defaultdict
by_column = defaultdict(list)

for row in rows:
   for k,v in row.iteritems():
       by_column[k].append(v)
```

Another option is [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> i = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep=' ')
>>> i
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
>>> i['A']
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think OP wants a dict that looks like `{'A': [all vals in column A], 'B': [all vals in column B]}`, not individual dicts for each row like `DictReader` provides.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is relevant, but you can do this using [rpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpy2).

```
from rpy2 import robjects
dframe = robjects.DataFrame.from_csvfile('/your/csv/file.csv', sep=' ')
d = dict([(k, list(v)) for k, v in dframe.items()])
```

output:

```
{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [7, 8, 9], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
```